# How to Invert Boolean logic statement which uses NULLs (Change a "SELECT" condition to a "DISCARD" condition)

Tags: java, null, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

**Short version:**

I need to convert a boolean expression:

( msg CONTAINS "A" ) or ( msg CONTAINS "B" ) or (msg CONTAINS "C") or (msg IS NULL)

to its inverse, but I am stumbling due to the use of "IS NULL".

The logic ***above reflects records I want to select***.   Unfortunately, ***I am only able to specify records I wish to discard***.

**Detail:**

I am using an application which parses records.   It allows the user to **FILTER OUT** (discard) records based on a boolean expression.  *(For those who care: Arcsight Smart Connectors -- it appears to be using a JRE  at its core, if that is relevant.)*

While this normally is sufficient, there are cases where I can only express what I want to SELECT. (and only those records).  Unfortunately, there is NO provision in the utilty  to do so, i.e. "FILTER IN".   I have no way to change this.

I learned a simple technique in most cases is to write my "selection" logic, and then invert it by encapsulating everything in parenthesis, swap AND for ORs and vice versa, and then prepend with a NOT.   (I only took 3 days of a symbolic logic class 20 years ago, so I brute forced this out, and so far it seems to work.)  However, this only works when NULLs are not in the picture.

"EQ" (equal) "NEQ" (not equal) , "CONTAINS", "NOT CONTAINS", "NOT" and "IS NOT NULL " are valid syntax for the expression

In addition to the constraint above, it should be clear that I have no way of knowing all the possible values of message.

I've gone through a lot of trial and error.  Probabbly not much value in listing out the attampts. But I'll mention a few points, snce I know that NULLS can be troublesome generally

===================

All help greatly appreciated. For the record, as stated above,  the engine underneath the app is some form of JRE (if that introduces and special treatment of NULLS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original expression:**

> ( msg CONTAINS "A" ) or ( msg CONTAINS "B" ) or (msg CONTAINS "C") or
>   (msg IS NULL)

**Desired inverse:**

> NOT ( ( msg CONTAINS "A" ) or ( msg CONTAINS "B" ) or (msg CONTAINS
>   "C") or (msg IS NULL) )

**DeMorgan's Theorem applied:**

> NOT( msg CONTAINS "A" ) AND NOT( msg CONTAINS "B" ) AND NOT(msg
>   CONTAINS "C") AND NOT(msg IS NULL)

**Using available primitives:**

> ( msg NOT CONTAINS "A" ) AND ( msg NOT CONTAINS "B" ) AND (msg NOT
>   CONTAINS "C") AND (msg IS NOT NULL)

**Optionally, using the commutative law of conjunction, move the NOT NULL test first:**

> (msg IS NOT NULL) AND (msg NOT CONTAINS "A") AND (msg NOT CONTAINS
>   "B") AND (msg NOT CONTAINS "C")

(Moving the NOT NULL test first may help if NOT CONTAINS fails when given a null first argument or if msg is NULL often and the system avoids performing the rest of the NOT CONTAINS checks.)

Comment: after so much experimentation, I sent straight to the final version of the query which appears to have done the trick.